# AngularJS Jasmine Unit Testing - How Do You Test a Function That Sets Individual Watches?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a function that looks like:

```
$scope.setUserWatch = function(userName){
    $scope.clearUserWatchs[userName] = $scope.$watch('user["' + userName + '"].value', function(newValue, oldValue){
        if(newValue != oldValue){
            if(newValue === false){
                $scope.customFunction(userName);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The above function allows me to set a watch on a specific `$scope` variable's `value` key on command.  Once the watch is set, I can also call a property of  `$scope.clearUserWatchs` to remove the watch.

I have the following test for the above function:

```
describe('setUserWatch Test', function(){
    it('should call scope.customFunction()', function(){
        var userName = 'tank';
        scope.user = {};
        scope.user[userName] = {
            value: false
        };
        spyOn(scope, 'customFunction');
        scope.setUserWatch(userName);
        scope.$apply();
        expect(scope.customFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith(userName);
    });
});
```

When I run the above test, none of the operations within the callback function for `$scope.$watch()` occurs.  In a traditional `$scope.$watch()` test (where the watch isn't encapsulated into an outer function), `scope.$apply` with the correct corresponding variable change will trigger the callback.

What needs to be done here to test this watch?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what I needed to do to test this `$watch()` on command function:

```
describe('setUserWatch  Test', function(){
    it('should call scope.customFunction()', function(){
        scope.user = {
            autumn: {
                value: true
            }
        };
        scope.$apply();
        scope.clearSeenWatchs = {};
        scope.user = {
            autumn: {
                value: false
            }
        };
        spyOn(scope, 'customFunction');
        scope.setUserWatch('autumn');
        scope.$apply();
        expect(scope.customFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

The first `scope.$apply()` gave the watched variable a value of `true`.  The second `scope.$apply()` gave it a value of `false`.  This allowed it to satisfy both the `newValue != oldValue` and `newValue === false` conditionals inside of the `$watch` callback.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't work in this way, as short test can proof it.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('UserCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.clearUserWatchs = {}
    $scope.customFunction = function(name) {};
    $scope.setUserWatch = function(userName) {
      $scope.clearUserWatchs[userName] = $scope.$watch('user["' + userName + '"].value', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue != oldValue) {
          if (newValue === false) {
            $scope.customFunction(userName);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });

describe('User', function() {
  beforeEach(module('app'));

  var scope, UserCtrl

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new()
    UserCtrl = $controller('UserCtrl', {
      $scope: scope
    })
  }));

  describe('setUserWatch Test', function() {
    it('true', function() {
      var userName = 'tank';
      scope.user = {};
      scope.user[userName] = {
        value: false
      };
      spyOn(scope, 'customFunction');
      scope.setUserWatch(userName);
      scope.$apply();
      expect(scope.customFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith(userName);
    })
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine-2.0.3-concated.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-mocks.js"></script>
```